# Bash Script has output from awk that combined several log files, unable to sort final output properly

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a Bash script that performs some awk magic on directory of logs and combines the results into one file...  The issue is that the logs contain a date on line 1 and data on line 2, date on line 3 and data on line 4, etc.  So when I sort it all the dates get sorted at top and all the data gets sorted at the bottom...  By the way the dates are not in order so thus I would like to sort them so they are...

Is there a way to group every 2 lines and then sort based on the first line of the group...

The date and data are on two separate lines

EXECUTING appears at the end of each date line so I am sure that could be key but unsure what tool to use for implementing this.

Here is a sample of the pre-sort output

```
2014-07-27 12:01:01,893] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:161086252)
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
2014-07-27 12:01:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
```

Here is a sample of the post-sort (sort some_file.log)

```
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
2014-07-27 12:01:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
2014-07-27 12:01:01,893] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:161086252)
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
```

Here is a sample of desired output

```
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
2014-07-27 12:00:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
2014-07-27 12:01:01,428] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:1961536860)
2014-07-27 12:01:01,893] [xxxxxxxxxxx] [ERROR] [xxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxx] EXECUTING
[5205003] Unable to find a user for user name or alias xxxxxx in group default. (Ref:161086252)
```

Rici's answer below is what worked for me...

```
cat  test.log | paste - - | sort | sed 's/\t/\n/' > testsort
```

Comment: It's a lot more helpful if you post the relevant portions of your code so people can help you accomplish your desired behavior.

Comment: You could just use a sort if *the date and corresponding data were on the same line*.

Comment: Is there some reason why the solution with `paste - -` didn't work for you? If so, could you explain why not?

Comment: There are no tabs.  I have something sorta working based on your answer but it is cutting the EXECUTING out of the date line which isn't the end of the world but I would prefer not too. here is my command I am running: cat test.log | paste - - | sort | sed 's/EXECUTING/\n/' >> testsort

Comment: Actually I reran Rici's first command and that worked as expected... Here is what worked: ->$ cat test.log | paste - - | sort | sed 's/\t/\n/' > testsort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chrisaycock noted in a comment, you could sort these easily if the date and data were on the same line. If you don't have an easy way to do this in your "awk magic", you can do it afterwards; it will be easy if there is some character which you know for sure is not in any date line, and even easier if that character is <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

*If you know that there is no tab character in any date line:*

```
awk magic files | paste - - | sort | sed 's/\t/\n/'
```

*If there are tabs in the date line, but no <kbd>|</kbd>:*

```
awk magic files | paste -d'|' - - | sort | sed 's/|/\n/'
```

The invocation `paste - -` reads two lines at a time from standard input and outputs them separated by the delimiter character (default tab, override with the `-d` flag). You can extend that by using more `-` and you can specify a sequence of delimiter characters:

```
$ seq 1 9 | paste -d:+ - - -
1:2+3
4:5+6
7:8+9
```

Comment: There are no tabs in the log file, just straight text however the delimiter may work...  There is the term EXECUTING at the end of every date line and (Ref:xxxxxxxx) at the end of the data line although it doesn't always contain the same number or amount of characters.  I have something sorta working based on above but it is cutting the EXECUTING out of the date line which isn't the end of the world but I would prefer not too.  [cat  test.log | paste - - | sort | sed 's/EXECUTING/\n/' >> testsort]

Comment: Actually I reran your first command and that worked as expected...  I have edited the main portion and here is what worked: ->$ cat  test.log | paste - - | sort | sed 's/\t/\n/' > testsort

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the value of the first column like this

```
 sort -k1,1nr -k2,2 logfile
```